# What is the weakest subsystem of Second-order Arithmetic (or its first-order part) that proves Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma?

Tags: computational-complexity, extremal-graph-theory, reverse-math

The question is in the title.  Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma is the following (according to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma)):

> For every $\epsilon \gt 0$ and positive integer $m$ there exists an integer $M$ such that if $G$ is a graph with at least $M$ vertices, there exists an integer $k$ in the range $m \le k \le M$ and an $\epsilon$-regular partition of the vertex set of $G$ into $k$ sets
> where a partition of the vertex set $V$ of $G$ into $k$ sets $\mathcal P = \{V_1,\dotsc, V_k\}$ is called an $\epsilon$-regular partition if
>
> $$\sum_{(V_i, V_j)} \lvert V_i\rvert\lvert V_j\rvert \le \lvert V(G)\rvert^2$$ where $(V_i, V_j)$ is not $\epsilon$-regular.

I conjecture that Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma is equivalent to $\mathit{ACA}_0$ over $\mathit{RCA}_0$ on the basis of the information contained in the MathOverflow question, "[The Reverse Mathematics of writing a set as a union](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71420/the-reverse-mathematics-of-writing-a-set-as-a-union)" (question 71420).  This is because the Regularity Lemma is an instance of the Union Principle and the Union Principle is equivalent to $\mathit{ACA}_0$ over $\mathit{RCA}_0$.

Is this point of view correct, or am I missing something?

[Addendum.  It should be noted that the Wikipedia entry, "[Elementary Function Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic)", makes the the claim that that Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma is a "natural example" of an "arithmetical statement" that is "true but unprovable in EFA, $\ge$".  Furthermore, the paper, "[The Algorithmic Aspects of the Regularity Lemma](https://doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1994.1005)" (by Alon, Duke, Lefmann, Rodl, and Yuster), claims that "we show how to obtain, for any input graph, a partition with the properties guaranteed by the lemma, efficiently [in polynomial time ($\Delta^{p}_1$)—my comment]" while claimimg that the problem of "deciding if the given partition[s] [of the partition given by the aforementioned algorithm—my comment] is $\epsilon$-regular" is "co-NP-complete"[$\Pi^{p}_1$].  Certainly, neither of the claims take the proof of Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma out of $\mathit{RCA}_{0}$ but are the two subsystems of $\mathit{RCA}_{0}$ mentioned in this addendum the same subsystem?  Lastly, in the paper, "[Reverse Mathematics and Recursive Graph Theory](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.19980440405)" [by Gasarch—my comment], it is claimed that the theorems regarding sequences of graphs in the paper are equivalent to $\mathit{ACA}_{0}$ or higher [Theorem 20 claims that the sequence of graphs mentioned in the theorem is equivalent to $\Pi^{1}_{1}$-$\mathit{CA}_{0}$.  Isn't Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma a statement about the sequence of all finite graphs and as such possibly equivalent to $ACA_{0}$?]

Comment: If memory serves, the usual proof of Szemeredi actually goes through in $\mathsf{RCA_0}$ alone (and [Friedman conjectures](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2003-November/007669.html) that Szemeredi is equivalent to EFA over bounded arithmetic). Certainly since Szemeredi is about **finite** graphs, it has nothing to do with $\mathsf{ACA_0}$; it's already going to be provable in $\mathsf{I\Sigma_n}$ for some fixed $n$ (and I suspect $n=1$ is already enough).

Comment: Then is the 'Union Principle' exposited in the mathoverflow question I mentioned actually provable in $I$$\Sigma_n$ when restricted to finite sets?

Comment: Also, I didn't see that Prof. Friedman explicitly mentioned the Regularity Lemma in the FoM post you provided the link to though I am definitely aware of both of his Grand Conjectures.

Comment: If you could provide the proof that the Regularity Lemma is provable in $RCA_0$ or $I$$\Sigma_n$ in an answer I would, of course, accept it....

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  have you any reference that shows that "the usual proof of Szemeredi actually goes through in $RCA_{0}$ alone"? that would be very helpful to me to study.  Thanks in advance for your help in this matter.  It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks.  Will correct.

Comment: Where does it cut off mid-sentence?

Comment: @LSpice: please do.  Thanks.

Comment: [Done](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424061/what-is-the-weakest-subsystem-of-second-order-arithmetic-or-its-first-order-par#comment1094983_424061).

Comment: @LSpice:  Again, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I don't know a reference, I just skimmed a proof and didn't see a step that didn't go through in $\mathsf{RCA_0}$ alone. If I get a chance this coming weekend, I'll write a quick summary of a proof of Szemeredi and why each bit goes through in $\mathsf{RCA_0}$.

Comment: Szemerédi's lemma is a purely first-order arithmetical statement, and as such it cannot imply ACA_0 over RCA_0. Moreover, if it is provable in ACA_0, then it is provable in PA by arithmetical conservativity, and therefore (as Noah already mentioned) in $I\Sigma_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  for a Hamiltonian graph, would the property that makes that graph Hamiltonian also be able to be expressed as a first-order arithmetical statement?

Comment: For a finite graph, yes. In second-order arithmetic, all finite (i.e., bounded) sets can be represented by numbers.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  Thanks.  Very helpful.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  Can you then characterize all finite hamiltonian graphs by this numbering?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "characterize" and "numbering", and what all this has to do with Szemerédi's lemma.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  How ( for example) would you represent the simplest hamiltonian graph (a triangle--three vertices and three edges) by numbers?

Comment: In reverse mathematics?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Are you saying Szemeredi is provable in EFA? But according to [Richard Borcherds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36580/is-all-ordinary-mathematics-contained-in-high-school-mathematics), the tower type lower bound for the regularity lemma means it cannot be proven in EFA

Comment: @Lxm I think I very clearly referred to $\mathsf{RCA_0}$, not $\mathsf{EFA}$ (which is much weaker); I only mentioned EFA at all in the context of a claim by Friedman.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was talking about your first comment, which mentioned the conjecture by Friedman, which I understood to be false

Comment: @Lxm Ah. Yes, that conjecture looks incorrect based on the bounds gotten. Certainly all I'll actively claim is that $\mathsf{RCA_0}$ suffices for the usual proof to go through.